# Meaning of "natural operator or a natural quadratic form"

Tags: terminology

I'm reading [these lecture notes](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/561/lect01-12.pdf) and I am confused about the use of the phrase "natural operator" and "natural quadratic" on page three.

> While the adjacency matrix is the most natural matrix to associate with a graph, I also ﬁnd it the
>   least useful. Eigenvalues and eigenvectors are most meaningful when used to understand a natural
>   operator or a natural quadratic form. The adjacency matrix provides neither.

Can someone explain to me what these phrases mean? Does "natural" refer to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: It has shades of the technical meaning from category theory, but I guess it is something looser than this: roughly speaking, "making no arbitrary choices."

Comment: What text can I read to develop some understanding or intuition about this word? Can be at the undergraduate or (if necessary) the graduate level. Any category theory text?

Comment: I would ignore it for now. The understanding will come gradually.